# Express.js session lost after about 3min

Tags: node.js, express, session, server-side

I use express.js and React. After success login I store `user_id` in session but after 2-3min session is lost and when I refresh page they log out me.
Here is my server.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection  = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'host',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'database',
  pool     : { maxConnections: 50, maxIdleTime: 30},
});

connection.connect(function(error){
    if(!!error){
        console.log('error');
    }else{
        console.log('Connected');
    }
})
//pluginy
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
//ustwienia
app.use(bodyParser()); //przesylanie danych w req.body
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
    secret: 'v8bRRj7XVC6Dvp',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    cookie: {secure: true}
}));
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/src'));
app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.use('/php', express.static(__dirname + '/php'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine','pug');

function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
    console.log('User id: '+req.session.user_id);

  if (!req.session.user_id) {
      if(req.route.path=='/'){
          res.render("indexNotLogin",{title:''});
      }else{
        res.send('You are not authorized to view this page');
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

//roots
    //index
    app.get('/', checkAuth, function(req, res){
        res.render("index",{title:''});
    })
    //funkcje
    app.get('/funkcje', function(req, res){
        res.render("funkcje",{title:''});
    })

//trylogin
    app.post('/trylogin', function(req, res){
        var username = req.body.name;
        var password = req.body.password;
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='"+username+"' AND pass='"+password+"' LIMIT 1", function(error, rows,fields){
            //callback
            if(!!error){
                console.log('error in query');
            }else{
                if(rows.length){
                    console.log(rows[0].id)
                    req.session.user_id = rows[0].id;
                    res.redirect('/');
                }else{
                    res.send('user dont exist')
                }
            }
        })

    })
app.listen(3000,'0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log('Port: 3000')
})
```

after form submit I do function `/trylogin` and eveything work fine, `req.session.user_id = rows[0].id` is user_id, but why session is lost so fast ?

Answer (score 2):

You can increase your session time by using `maxAge` option in session middleware:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'v8bRRj7XVC6Dvp',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    cookie: {maxAge:900000} //here ,15 min session time
}));
```

Comment: If I use cookie: `{secure: true,maxAge:900000}` my session dont work but if I set `{secure: false,maxAge:900000}`  this work fine. Do you know how I can fix this ?

Comment: _secure_  is basically used for https connection not plain http. If you think 
 its not neccessary then i think you shouldnt use.

Comment: My session still dont work the same problem hmm... I used `{secure: false,maxAge:900000}` on end of script I have `app.listen(3000, function(){})` I forgot add this in post. Do you know why this still work only for 2-3min ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using `express-mysql-session` package.

```
//import
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

let options = {
  host: process.env.hostNameDB,
  port: 3306,
  user: process.env.userNameDB,
  password: process.env.passwordDB,
  database: process.env.databaseName,
  expiration: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  clearExpired: true,
  checkExpirationInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, //per day db cleaning
};

let sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);

app.use(session({
  key: 'session_cookie_name',
  secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
  store: sessionStore,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}));
```

By using this package you can store your session data properly and then it will delete the data from DB when `checkExpirationInterval` is crossed.