# Express.js session lost after about 3min (I Have the same issue )

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I am facing the same issue like this question: [Express.js session lost after about 3min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535987/express-js-session-lost-after-about-3min)

But can't find any solution yet.

My Session Code:

```
app.use(
session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {secure: true, maxAge: 1000*60*60*24}
}) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by using `express-mysql-session` package.

```
//import
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

let options = {
 host: process.env.hostNameDB,
 port: 3306,
 user: process.env.userNameDB,
 password: process.env.passwordDB,
 database: process.env.databaseName,
 expiration: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
 clearExpired: true,
 checkExpirationInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, //per day db cleaning
};

let sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);

app.use(session({
 key: 'session_cookie_name',
 secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
 store: sessionStore,
 resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

By using this package you can store your session data properly and then it will delete the data from DB when `checkExpirationInterval` is crossed.